# Ajax submit returning Error but updating the database fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

```
<script>
        function addprescription() {
            var Case_Histroy=$('#Case_Histroy').val();
            var Medication=$('#Medication').val();
            var Note=$('#Note').val();
            var pname="<?php echo($patient->getUsername()); ?>";
            var dname="<?php echo($doctor->getUsername()); ?>";
            var id="<?php echo($id); ?>";
            frmData={Case_Histroy:Case_Histroy,Medication:Medication,Note:Note,pname:pname,dname:dname,id:id}
            console.log( frmData);
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "loadfiles/AddAppointmentSubmit.php",
                    data: frmData,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                        $("#alert").html(msg)
                    }
                    ,
                error : function () {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
        }
</script>
```

I have a function to submit the form. But ajax function alerts its as failure. But data base seems to be updated. when I click the button. I couldn't find the reason for the cause in the console.

this is the php file

```
<?php
echo "I'm in";
include "../../Adaptor/mysql_crud.php";
include ("Prescription.php");
$prescription=new Prescription();
if(isset($_POST)){
    $Note=htmlspecialchars($_POST['Note']);
    $Case_Histroy=htmlspecialchars($_POST['Case_Histroy']);
    $medication = htmlspecialchars($_POST['Medication']);
    $pname=$_POST['pname'];
    $danme=$_POST['dname'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $prescription->insert($pname,$danme,$Case_Histroy,$medication,$Note,$id);
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="alert"><strong><?php echo "Submitted succesfully"; ?></strong></div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: try adding `dataType: 'html'` to your ajax parameters.

`$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "loadfiles/AddAppointmentSubmit.php",
                    data: frmData,
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg);
                        $("#alert").html(msg)
                    }

Comment: @ShaileshLadumor It returns just an alert saying "failure"

Comment: @Difster yha it's working fine . thank you. what's the purpose of puttin data type as html what's the reason behind the error?

Comment: If dataType is not specified, it will make a best guess. And maybe for some reason it didn't guess right for you. But specifying the dataType makes it certain.

Comment: @Difster The answer you suggested not working! properly it works fine sometimes !

Comment: You don't seem to have any error handling in your PHP. So if the PHP fails, you're not going to get a properly formatted html string back.

Comment: XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost/MedicareClinicSystemFinalProject/Doctor/loadfiles/AddAppointmentSubmit.php". this is the error i got in console @Difster

Comment: I added an answer. Check that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `else` statement to your `if`:

insert($pname,$danme,$Case_Histroy,$medication,$Note,$id);
    ?>
    

}
?>

Also, it's not necessary to stick the php in the middle of the `<div>` you can just use `echo` at the beginning since you're not introducing any variables to it:

```
echo '<div class="alert alert-success" id="alert"><strong>Submitted successfully</strong></div>';
```

Comment: Finally I think I got the answer! thanks for make me keep guessing!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Please mark the answer as solved. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the answer for the Problem! Actual problem is button that fired up the AJAX request also reloaded the page interrupting AJAX inner workings. So the error message will be alerted.

I tried this code.

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#button_Add_p").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var Case_Histroy=$('#Case_Histroy').val();
            var Medication=$('#Medication').val();
            var Note=$('#Note').val();
            var pname="<?php echo($patient->getUsername()); ?>";
            var dname="<?php echo($doctor->getUsername()); ?>";
            var id="<?php echo($id); ?>";
            frmData={Case_Histroy:Case_Histroy,Medication:Medication,Note:Note,pname:pname,dname:dname,id:id}
            console.log( frmData);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'html',
                url: "loadfiles/AddAppointmentSubmit.php",
                data: frmData,
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                    $("#alert").html(msg)
                }
                ,
                error : function () {
                    alert("failure");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```